# PHP SQL query returns null

Tags: java, php, android

I'm working a school project where I design a banking app. I'm currently working on the basic layout and database connection for login and registration.
So my login and registration function work fine but when I tried to fetch the information that my PHP scripts returns I just returns null.
Here's my code:

My main class:

```
enter code here
package com.example.quinten.netpay;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Vars
    final Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    final Button btnReg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    final ProgressBar prgLogin = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prbLogin);
    final EditText txtGebruiksnaam = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNaam);
    final EditText txtWachtwoord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtWachtwoord);

    //ProgressSpiner onzichtbaar maken
    prgLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Button listeners
    //Login
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Nakijken of alle velden zijn ingevuld
            if(txtGebruiksnaam.getText().toString().equals("") || txtWachtwoord.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vul alle velden in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                //ProgressSpiner zichtbaar maken
                prgLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //Vars
                final String strGebruikersnaam = txtGebruiksnaam.getText().toString();
                final String strWachtwoord = txtWachtwoord.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonReponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonReponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                //Terugekregen gebruikersinfo ophalen
                                String strGebruikersnaamResp = jsonReponse.getString("Gebruikersnaam");
                                String strVoornaamResp = jsonReponse.getString("Voornaam");
                                String strAchternaamResp = jsonReponse.getString("Achternaam");
                                String strSaldoResp = jsonReponse.getString("Saldo");


                                //Menu openen en gebruikersinformatie doorgeven
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
                                intent.putExtra("gebruikersnaam", strGebruikersnaamResp);
                                intent.putExtra("voornaam", strVoornaamResp);
                                intent.putExtra("achternaam", strAchternaamResp);
                                intent.putExtra("saldo", strSaldoResp);
                                startActivity(intent);


                                //ProgressSpiner onzichtbaar maken
                                prgLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord niet correct!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //ProgressSpiner onzichtbaar maken
                                prgLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR!" + " " +  e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //ProgressSpiner onzichtbaar maken
                            prgLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(strGebruikersnaam, strWachtwoord, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);


            }

        }

    });



    //Registeren
    btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registreren.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}
}
```

My loginRequest class:

```
package com.example.quinten.netpay;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://37.34.58.100/~dragv/login.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public LoginRequest(String gebruikersnaam, String wachtwoord, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("gebruikersnaam", gebruikersnaam);
    params.put("wachtwoord", wachtwoord);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() { return params;
}



}
```

And my PHP script:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("Private");

$gebruikersnaam = $_POST["gebruikersnaam"];
$wachtwoord = $_POST["wachtwoord"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM Gebruikers WHERE Gebruikersnaam = ? AND Wachtwoord = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $gebruikersnaam, $wachtwoord);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $Gebruikersnaam, $Voornaam, $Achternaam, $Wachtwoord, $Saldo);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["Gebruikersnaam"] = $Gebruikersnaam;
    $response["Voornaam"] = $Voornaam;
    $response["Achternaam"] = $Achternaam;
    $response["Wachtwoord"] = $Wachtwoord;
    $response["Saldo"] = $Saldo;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/mysqli_error  on the query - anything come of it? I can't help with android/java stuff though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I didn't put all the columns of my database in the fetch statement.